# Gibt es andere Begriffe, die ähnlich gebildet sind wie »Vogel Strauß«?

Tags: compound, curiosity

Der Begriff *Vogel Strauß* ist ungewöhnlich, da

- im Gegensatz zu einer üblichen Wortzusammensetzung *(Straußenvogel)* die Spezifikation nachgestellt ist,
- es sich auch nicht um einen Eigennamen handelt, wie z. B. *Arche Noah, Insel Mainau* oder *Schweinchen Dick,*
- er eine feste Wendung ist, die auch verwendet wird, wenn keine Unterscheidungsbedarf besteht.

Ich bin neugierig: Gibt es andere derartige Wendungen im Deutschen?

Comment: Vergleichbar, wenn auch nicht real, wäre der [_Vogel Rock_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roch).

Comment: Meint du mit dem zweiten Punkt, dass es sich bei Strauss um den Gattungsnamen handelt? Also nicht etwas, dass "Arche Noah" oder "Insel Mainau" Eigennamen sind? Aus irgendwelchen Gründen kam mir auch "Reineke Fuchs" in den Sinn.

Comment: @Marakai: Ich bin nicht ganz sicher, dass ich Dich richtig verstehe, aber eher nicht. In *Arche Noah* und *Insel Mainau* ist der zweite Teil der spezifischere, genau so wie in *Vogel Strauß,* also sind die Konstruktionen in einem gewissen Sinn vergleichbar, außer eben, dass es sich dabei um Eigennamen handelt. *Reineke Fuchs* ist auch ein Eigenname, aber darüber hinaus anders gebildet, nämlich in Anlehnung an ein klassischen zweiteiligen Namen mit *Reineke* als Vor- und *Fuchs* als Nachnamen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Daher meine Frage. Wir suchen also nach <Oberbegriff> <Begriff>. Gevatter Tod sollte also auch nicht passen. Hmmm...

Comment: Erstaunlicherweise machen ausgerechnet bei diesem Vogel andere europäische Sprachen dasselbe wie das Deutsche: Niederländisch: *struisvogel*, schwedisch: *fågeln struts*, oder sogar Latein *avis struthio* (Möglicherweise sind also die Römer schuld)

Comment: Der *See Genezareth* und der *Berg Ararat* (oder auch im Englischen: der *Mount Everest*, also keine rein deutsche Erscheinung) fällt mir noch dazu ein. Diese Ortsbezeichnungen dürften auch durch das Lateinische bei uns gelandet sein. Die *Arche Noah* halte ich nicht für gleich gebildet - Hier ist eher irgendwann mal ein Genitiv-s verschütt gegangen.

Comment: Möglicherweise ist dein Ansatz, Eigennamen auszuschliessen, genau der falsche -  Ich denke nämlich, dass der "Vogel Strauss" übersetzt aus dem Lateinischen "Avis Struthio" genau so zu seinem deutschen Begriff gekommen ist. "Struthio" war für die ersten Übersetzer ziemlich sicher nichts anderes als ein Eigenname. Das erklärt allerdings nicht, warum wir heute keinen "Vogel Pinguin" kennen...

Comment: Strauß ohne Vogel zu verwenden ist aber nicht unüblich, wenn keine Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Tulpenstrauß besteht. Straußeneier, Jagd auf den Strauß, ...

Comment: @userunknown: Das habe ich auch nie bestritten. Aber man wird auch nicht schief angeschaut, wenn man von »den Eiern des Vogels Strauß« spricht.

Comment: @userunknown Besonders bei der "Vogel-Strauß-Politik" war der *Vogel* in den letzten 50 Jahren durchaus hilfreich, um nicht auf Franz-Josef zu zielen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Unbestritten. Es gibt noch Ente Süß/Sauer.

Comment: @userunknown Die Ente ist - wie z.B "Forelle blau" - m.A. nach was ganz anderes.

Answer (score 4):

Ich versuche mich mal an einer Antwort, die den Faden von einigen meiner und anderer Kommentare aufnimmt und weiterspinnt:

Zunächst einmal ist die Bildung „Vogel Strauß“ und „Vogel Roch“ für mich *ursprünglich* dieselbe Begriffsbildung wie „Insel Mainau“ und „See Genezareth“. Ganz einfach, weil ein neues, „fremdländisches Wort“ im Deutschen immer zuerst als Eigennamen aufgefasst wird (eher: wurde) und daher auch in einer solchen Paarung mit seinem Oberbegriff auftaucht. Erst die Assimilation in die Sprache und ein allgemeines „Annehmen“ des Begriffes sorgt dafür, dass der Begriff sein Beiwort mit der Zeit verliert. Dieses Voransetzen des Oberbegriffs vor Eigennamen ist eine sprachliche Eigenart, die wir wahrscheinlich aus dem Lateinischen übernommen haben und die früh in „gebildetes Deutsch“ einging. Heute gibt es diese Assimilationsform m. A. nach (vielleicht, weil Latein seinen Anspruch als universelle Wissenschaftssprache inzwischen verloren hat) nicht mehr, wir übernehmen einfach den fremden Begriff ohne weitere Erklärung.

Beim Vogel Roch aus der Sage (schönes Beispiel, übrigens) ist das mangels realem Gegenstück so geblieben – diese Form betrachte ich übrigens aus ebendiesem Grund als Eigennamen – der Strauß dagegen hat seinen Eingang in die Zoos und in die Sprache gefunden und wird heute sehr viel öfter auch ohne seinen Oberbegriff verwendet (*Straußeneier, Straußenfeder, Straußenfarm, Straußenleder*, …). Es hat wohl nur „etwas länger“ gedauert, weil die Eindeutschung „Strauß“ zu allem Übel auch noch ein Homonym bildet (früher ein mehrfaches, siehe „einen Strauß ausfechten“), was den Vorgang wohl gebremst hat.

Beim Begriff „Vogel-Strauß-Politik“ (Kopf in den Sand stecken), wird der Vogel heute fast immer vorgesetzt, um den ehemaligen bayrischen Ministerpräsidenten nicht mit hineinzuziehen.

(Nehmen wir mal an, es würde in einem fernen Land ein neuer Tiefseefisch entdeckt, dessen Verhalten z. B. hauptsächlich daraus bestünde, das Maul weit aufzureißen. Nehmen wir weiterhin an, der hieße Cehopher in der Landessprache und man würde den Begriff Cehopher-Politik als Politik der Drohgebärde ins Deutsche übernehmen – auch da würde diese Politikform wahrscheinlich ziemlich lange aus naheliegenden Gründen als „Fisch-Cehopher-Politik“ zusammen mit dem Oberbegriff verwendet werden ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Ich nehme stark an, dass es sich hier um einen *Homonymzusatz* handelt, siehe [Wikipedia: Homonym](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym). Da dort nur eine sehr überschaubare Anzahl von Homonymen genannt ist, und die meisten sich entweder im Geschlecht unterscheiden (so dass die gemeinte Bedeutung sich aus dem Artikel ergibt), oder, wie *Mutter*, thematisch so weit auseinanderliegen, dass die Eindeutigkeit über den Kontext hergestellt wird, halte ich für möglich, dass es sich um ein recht seltenes Konstrukt handelt.